# Unable to run TcmTemplateBuilder on my local machine

Tags: 2013, template-builder, 2013-sp1

Experts,

I am trying to run Template Builder (2013 sp1) on my machine, while running `TcmTemplateBuilder.application` (ClickOnce Application), getting the error.

I have template builder for 2011 already installed on my machine. Could it be the reason and I should uninstall it first?

I am pasting the Error details below:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.296
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/saugangw/Downloads/TcmTemplateBuilder.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : TcmTemplateBuilder.application, Version=7.1.0.114, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cefdd28298bce0cb, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\saugangw\Downloads\TcmTemplateBuilder.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [12-03-2014 13:24:10] : Activation of C:\Users\saugangw\Downloads\TcmTemplateBuilder.application has started.
    * [12-03-2014 13:24:10] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [12-03-2014 13:24:10] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [12-03-2014 13:24:10] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Deployment URL is showing as: Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/saugangw/Downloads/TcmTemplateBuilder.application - did you copy the application to your local machine, or use a non-IE browser?

Point IE to http://[YourCMEURL]/TemplateBuilder/TcmTemplateBuilder.application

Comment: hi, I was using a non IE browser. Using IE solves the issue. thanks

Comment: If you want to use chrome then use the ClickOnce extension and it will work.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl?hl=en

Similar extension is available for FireFox as well

Comment: For IE, also make sure you do have the CME URL among "Trusted Sites" in your Internet Options -> Security tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the template builder from some other version as compared to your current version; then yes, you need to un-install the previous version and re-install it for 2013

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it worked without un-installing the previous one.

Comment: Glad to know that it is fixed.

Answer (score -3):

Use below mentioned URL pattern to run the template builder installer:

**[http/https]://[YourCMEURL]/TemplateBuilder/TcmTemplateBuilder.application**